# Why there is a large red margin on top of select box?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/elastic-worker-vg4joq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Here's the code

```
import "./styles.css";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactSelect, { components } from "react-select";
import ArrowDropDown from "./ArrowDropDown.svg";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const selectStyles = {
  control: (style) => ({
    ...style,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    gap: "24px",
    width: "580px",
    background: "rgba(217, 237, 255, 0.32)",
    border: "1px solid rgba(43, 69, 87, 0.24)",
    borderRadius: "4px"
  }),
  input: (style) => ({
    ...style,
    marginLeft: "12px",
    marginTop: "12px",
    font: "14px/20px var(--notosans)"
  }),
  menu: (style) => ({
    ...style,
    width: "580px",
    font: "14px/20px var(--notosans)"
  }),
  dropdownIndicator: (style) => ({
    ...style,
    marginRight: "5px"
  }),
  singleValue: (style) => ({
    ...style,
    color: "#2B4557",
    marginLeft: "12px",
    marginBottom: "12px",
    font: "14px/20px var(--notosans)"
  }),
  indicatorSeparator: (style) => ({
    ...style,
    display: "none"
  }),
  placeholder: (style, state) => ({
    ...style,
    display: "none"
  })
};

const DropdownIndicator = (props) => {
  return (
    <components.DropdownIndicator
      {...props}
      isFocused={props.isFocused && props.selectProps.menuIsOpen}
    >
      <img src={ArrowDropDown} alt="Arrow Down" />
    </components.DropdownIndicator>
  );
};
const { Option } = components;

const CustomOption = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <Option {...props}>
    <strong>{children} hello</strong>
    <span style={{ color: "blue" }}>abv</span>
    <button>hello</button>
  </Option>
);

const CustomOption1 = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <Option {...props}>
    <strong>{children} hello</strong>
    <span style={{ color: "blue" }}>abv</span>
    <button>hello</button>
  </Option>
);

const Select = ({
  placeholder,
  options,
  onChange,
  value,
  id,
  disabled,
  isSearchable
}) => {
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
  return (
    <ReactSelect
      instanceId={id}
      value={options.find((option) => option.value === value) || {}}
      styles={selectStyles}
      components={{
        DropdownIndicator,
        Option: CustomOption,
        SingleValue: CustomOption1
      }}
      options={options}
      onChange={(value) => onChange(value)}
      onFocus={() => setFocused(true)}
      onBlur={() => setFocused(false)}
      isDisabled={disabled}
      isSearchable={isSearchable}
    />
  );
};

const options = [
  { value: "option1", label: "Option 1" },
  { value: "option2", label: "Option 2" },
  { value: "option3", label: "Option 3" }
];

const App = () => {
  const handleChange = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Dropdown List</h1>
      <Select
        placeholder="Select an option"
        options={options}
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={options[0].value}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
// ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image]

Why there is a large red margin on top of select box?

Comment: You can press `Ctrl+Shift+I` to use developer tools and see manually what stylesheet did that.

Answer (score 1):

React Select places an `<input />` element in which the user can start typing to filter the options:
[image]

---

You can disable it by setting the following prop to `false`:

```
isSearchable={false}
```

You do have that prop listen in your prop destructing, but since you're not passing a value, nor have a default value, it's `undefined`, which enables the feature.